# Faster way to insert only 1 row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

i have a group by query which returns only 1 row with 4 columns. when i run this select query it takes 1-2 minutes as the tables involved  in this query are very huge( one of the tables has 60 million records) but when i use this query in insert statement it takes about 10 minutes or more.

can someone tell the reason behind it? I am inserting just one row which should take 1 minute time but why it is taking 10 minutes? also please provide some suggestions to tackle this type of problem as on searching i am mostly finding faster methods for bulk insert. below is the query structure for review

```
select col1, count(loan), sum(A), sum(B) 
from
(select 'dummy' as col1, X.loan, BT.A, BT.B,
row_number() over (partition by X.loan order by BT.C desc) rnum
from Big_Table BT, X
where X.loan = BT.loan
and  X.date<  "some date"
and X.date>"another date")
where rnum =1
and B> "some value"
group by col1
```

For Big_Table indexes are on columns loan and C.

Comment: One thing that can be worth trying is adding an explicit "limit 1", so that the DBMS knows it can stop after calculating the first row. Also, in your example at least, the `group by col1` is doing nothing, since `col1 = 'dummy'` for every row of the inner query.

Comment: I will try adding limit 1. the dummy column col1 is like a timestamp whenever i insert data i put a date like addition_date instead of dummy value however this can be put outside the inner query too.

Comment: If col1 was outside the inner query, you could remove the Group By, which might well simplify (and thus speed up) the query plan generated.

Comment: Can you post the plans for both the INSERT and the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

This query may get you the same result faster:

```
SELECT "dummy", COUNT(BT.loan), SUM(BT.A), SUM(BT.B)
FROM Big_Table BT
JOIN (
  SELECT X.loan, max(BT.C) as C
  FROM X
  JOIN Big_Table BT ON X.loan = BT.loan
  WHERE X.date > "some date"
    AND X.date < "another date"
  GROUP BY X.loan ) partitioned
ON BT.loan = partitioned.loan AND BT.C = partitioned.C
WHERE BT.B > "some value"
```

And make sure you have an index on X for `loan` and `date` and on Big_Table for `loan`, `C`, and `B`.